# Django Main Category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am very beginner in django..I am trying to upload product by 2 main categories For him(man) and For her(woman)...but its not working properly...i have used to method in template to get categories...when i click on the for him it will redirect me to products which i added in for him(man)..but in template the url tag {%url '' %} is not proper i think..when i used url tag it shows me attribute error...And if used get_absolute_url in template the whole link was hide..plz anyone can help me to solve this problem.

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
```

## Create your models here.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug =  models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shops:shop_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Subcategory(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='subcategorymans', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Product(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='productsman', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, related_name='productsman2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    brand= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my model.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from .models import Product,Category
```

## Create your views here.

```
    def Shop(request):
        product_shop = Product.objects.all()
    
        template = 'product/shop.html'
    
        context = {'product_shop':product_shop}
        return render(request, template, context)
   
    
    

    def Shop_Category(request, category_slug=None):
        category=None
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        products= Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
            products = products.filter(category=category)
    
        template = 'product/shop.html'
    
        context = {'products':products, 'category':category, 'categories':categories}
    
        return render(request, template, context)
```

#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
app_name = 'shops'

urlpatterns = (
    path('shop/', views.Shop, name='shop'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.Shop_Category, name='shop_by_category')
)

<div class="sidebar four columns">
                <div class="widget-area clearfix ">
                    <aside class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories">
                        <h3>CATEEGORIES</h3>
                        <ul class="product-categories">
                            {% if categories %}
                                {% for category in categories %}
                            <li class="cat-item cat-item-27 cat-parent">
                                <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">For her</a>
                                <ul class='children'>
                                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-32">
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Accessories</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Blouses</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Jackets</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Shoes</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="for-him.html">For him</a>
                                <ul class='children'>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Accessories</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Shirts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Shoes</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="category_page.html">Trousers</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                    <aside class="widget_text widget widget_custom_html">
                        <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
                            <div style="text-align:center; padding:20px 10px; border:2px solid #e9c445;">
                                <h3>SIGN UP FOR
                                    <br>
                                    NEWSLETTER</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Aenean ligula nibh, mole stie id viverra a, dapibus ante lobortis
                                </p>
                                <a class="button button_size_2 button_js" href="#" style=" background-color:#e9c445 !important; color:#000;"><span class="button_label">Subscribe</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my template...for shop

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the Urlpattern syntax . it should be under Square brackets []  not the () parentheses.